# How can I configure Index position of Transaction in the block?

Tags: web3.py, bsc, nonce

How can I configure Index position of Transaction in the block?[image]  web3.py

Comment: You mean set the transaction position within the block? Usually miners sort transactions by gasPrice so setting a high gasPrice might help selecting a position close to 0, but it is not guarantee. Miners can arbitrarily order transactions in the block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define the inde of the transaction. This is done by miners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
print(w3.eth.get_transaction("tx-hash")["transactionIndex"])
```

Example:

```
w3.eth.get_transaction("0xb517b5e17550aa062870d6eb685e55b011173ede61970cab955ffc3fc211e656")["transactionIndex"]
```

prints 75, which matches the [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb517b5e17550aa062870d6eb685e55b011173ede61970cab955ffc3fc211e656).

Comment: If I want to define index in transaction

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the nonce or the transaction index? Because transaction index are done by miners based upon gas fee you are willing to pay.

With nonce, it depends on the account that is doing the transactions.

Comment: If I want to define an index in a transaction starting from zero